# Why do Docker Nginx proxies require access to the Docker Socket?

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've noticed that pretty much every implementation of a Docker reverse proxy requires access to the Docker socket. From what I can tell, this is because the proxy grabs some configuration from the application container. My sense is that this configuration could simply be moved to the proxy container, and starting/stopping the proxy could be a manual operation to avoid the requirement for container communication. Is there some aspect of this I am missing? What exactly does the Docker socket do to enable the reverse proxy?

Comment: There's a setup using Traefik that dynamically creates HTTP endpoints based on containers existing; is that what you're looking at?  The setup I describe in [this answer](/a/77060234), for example, includes an Nginx-based reverse proxy but doesn't use the Docker socket.

Comment: Hrm, I think the key with the Docker socket role in the reverse proxy is that it enables custom host names, which I don't think that approach enables? Even with Traefik if you want custom local host name I think you need to use the Docker socket, but I'm really not sure why that is.

Comment: Maybe you can [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?